# MySQL table not updated on UPDATE query (from Facebook graph call)

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, json, facebook-graph-api

I'm having trouble updating data in a MySQL table. I'm using a while loop to run through all the rows of the table. All of the images display correctly (so I know that the images are right). It is grabbing the gender data because I can echo the genders out too. What I want to do is take the data, grab it and enter it in the MySQL for the appropriate facebook id so the query will run quicker in the future (basically I want to grab it from the MySQL table instead of calling from the Facebook Graph everytime since the Facebook graph seems to be going pretty slow). I figured I'd just run this once and dump all the data in the table but when I run it, the table doesn't update. Be aware that I'm update a table called "fb_id" which also has a row called "fb_id". This is why it is displayed twice:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){                          
                    echo "<a href='http://www.facebook.com/".$row['fb_id']."' target='_blank'><img src='http://graph.facebook.com/".$row['fb_id']."/picture/' /></a>";

                    $jsonurl = "https://graph.facebook.com/".$row['fb_id'];
                    $json = file_get_contents($jsonurl,0,null,null);
                    $json_output = json_decode($json);
                    $user_gender = $json_output->gender;

                    $sql_update = "UPDATE fb_id SET gender='$user_gender' WHERE fb_id='$fb_id'";
                    $update_result = $mysqli->query($sql_update);
                    }
```

Any idea where I'm going wrong here? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$fb_id`

Used in the SQL query doesn't seem defined anywhere. Shouldn't you replace that with:

`$row['fb_id']?`

Comment: Oh man, yes. Easy as that. Thank you. (I can accept in ten minutes...)

Comment: Don't worry. Sometimes you just need another pair of eyes for a short while :)

Comment: Additionally you should try to use prepared statements. SQL injection prevention!